# What are the exact dimensions of this screw?

Tags: technical-drawing

When working on a technical drawing project, I couldn't find the exact dimensions of the following screw

[image]

In particular, I don't understand the $0.5:1$ to $\emptyset 15$ indication.

Is this screw in any DIN/ISO (maybe DIN 914 or ISO 4027) standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanded from Solar Mike's answer:

The screw is 8mm in diameter, 22mm long, has a thread every 1.25mm, and the tip is 5mm in diameter, tapered down from the full screw diameter (8mm) with 0.5(H): 1(V) tapering.

Answer (score 1):

That says taper point diameter 5 to the full diameter.

It is 22 long M8

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my first language. What do you mean by diameter 5 to the full diameter? The taper begins with a diameter of 8, and then for every mm down, the diameter of the taper shrinks by 0.5 mm until it has diameter 5?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, specifically how the taper callout works.